# Why does a room not warm up faster when I put the heater's thermostat on a higher value?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, everyday-life

I would say it should warm up faster because the difference in temperature between the room and heater is higher.

Edit: I am talking about a convection heater.

Comment: Some new furnaces & most heaters have multiple heat outputs (high/med/lo), so maybe yours is broken. (Or does "heater" have some special physics meaning I don't know? Doesn't seem like a "physics" question...)

Comment: To answer your question with a question: why would you want it to work like that? Artificially not warming as fast as its able to when the error is only small

Comment: @RichardTingle Well, many simple feedback systems we learn about are "proportional" systems that do exactly this.

Comment: Any heater that did that would be poorly designed. If I really want the room to reach 70 degrees as quickly as possible, I have to set it to 90 degrees, then wait until it hits 70, and then set it to 70? If I wanted to have to watch the temperature and change things based on it, why do I have a thermostat?

Comment: @RichardTingle That's how most newer inverter-driven heat-pumps/AC units work. By slowing down when it gets near the set temperature, it can run at a constant low speed rather than cycling on and off. Helps reduce the 'cold wind' effect and runs more efficiently.

Comment: @Someone right, to avoid overshooting and maintain a constant value. But if you're 5 degrees away or 1000 degrees away it should still heat as much as it can. If it's 0.5 degrees away then fair enough on slowing down to avoid overshoot

Comment: There's an interesting paper ("Two Theories of Home Heat Control", Kempton 1986) which studies the mental models that people develop about how thermostats work. The data is sparse, but the author estimates that 25% to 50% of Americans believe setting a higher temperature will heat up the room faster.

Comment: If it's a two stage unit, it will. But usually not because it's set higher. It will switch to the 2nd stage if it runs *long* enough.

Comment: I had a renter who could not understand this.  Feel cold, turn the dial all the way up.  Feel hot, all the way off.  Then complain to me about the eight hundred dollar utility bill.

Comment: Actually, my car works this way.  It has a "smart" temperature controller.  (I think most folks would call it "dumb", but the manufacturer thinks it's "smart".)

Comment: Note: This might be different from thermostat to "thermostat". Especially mechanical (in contrast to electronic)(usually based on thermal expansion) thermostats (typical for hot-water based central heating) are of varying quality. A good mechanical thermostat has an operating range of 1°C, meaning room temperature is 0,5°C below selected valve is fully open and 0,5°C above selected valve is fully closed and otherwise some value in between. However very cheap or very old "thermostats" may act as you expect: "Medium temp" might mean "valve medium open" for them, regardless of temperature.

Comment: @David: It's likely true with a heat pump system that has backup electrical "em heat" - the thermostat usually activates the latter when the current and target temp differ by more than a few degrees.

Comment: FWIW this is not really a physics question, more about engineering and the design/operating principles of everyday things.

Comment: @AnthonyX when I posted this question I thought the explanation would be physical rather than "a thermostat doesn't work the way you think it does".

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Because you're only changing the temperature at which the heater is supposed to stop working.

It is always working at the same power, regardless the temperature difference. But for higher temperature it will have to heat at this same power for longer time.

So in short: You don't change the difference in temperature between heater and the room.

Comment: Oh, that's what I got wrong all the time. I was assuming the heater would heat at a higher temperature when I put the thermostat on a higher setting until that temperature was reached. I didn't know heaters would always run at maximum power regardless of the setting. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Limechime The same is generally true of microwaves as well. When you set a microwave to 50% power and 3 minutes, it's not actually running at 50% power continuously for 3 minutes, it's running at 100% power only 50% of the time, generally alternating between off and full on for ~15 seconds at a time; which usually results in the sound the microwave makes changing every time it switches on/off.

Comment: Many things, including heaters, microwave ovens and air conditioners use a very coarse-grained binary Pulse Width Modulation technique.  The heating element / magnetron / compressor is either off or on.  The control mechanism turns it off (multiple seconds or longer) and on (multiple seconds or longer) to achieve the desired temperature / power level.  This is something Dr Fred Brooks calls out in "The Design of Design."  Most people do NOT understand this.  Once they do, many behaviors no longer make sense (turning the AC colder, trying to cool off the room faster, etc.).

Comment: @Limechime: Think of it this way: If I put the pedal to the metal, my car will accelerate at the same rate from 0-100 km/h, regardless of whether I'm trying to reach a top speed of 100 km/h or 200 km/h.

Comment: Unless you actually have a furnace with damping installed.

Comment: If your appliance has an "intensity" setting, then modifying that will change the temperature faster. For example, my car AC has a separate temperature and fan intensity control. To cool the car faster, I use the second.

Comment: Another appliance where this happens to calamitous effect is regular ovens.

Comment: @StellaBiderman this is not completely true: if the car fan blows harder, the air is not as cool coming out of the vents as if it blows less hard. But you get more air, and it reaches more of the car faster. The cooling element is removing a fixed amount of heat from the air, whether a small amount of air moves over it, or a lot. Same with heating. So if you are cold, turning the blower high might make you feel cold even if it is providing heat. Moving air will cool *you* (but not the inside of the car) even without A/C, because you sweat (and the car doesn't). Another area of confusion.

Comment: @nocomprende thanks for the information. I guess I hadn't thought about that, but what you've said seems correct to me.

Comment: Many portable home heaters have a low/med/high setting AND a thermostat.  the thermostat is still binary but high will heat the room to that temperature more quickly.  Also my car (Chevy Volt) does exactly what you suggest--As you approach the temperature the heat and fan kick down but don't shut off to conserve electricity.

Comment: @Shufflepants: Most microwaves.  I was once surprised to encounter one that actually did reduce the power output instead of cycling.

Comment: @Limechime - " I was assuming the heater would heat at a higher temperature when I put the thermostat on a higher setting " Well, some do. They are called proportional heaters. But such heaters are simply not found as room heaters. It's much more economical to use a single-heat heater, and turn it on and off as necessary. This produces slight temperature swings, but nobody notices.

Comment: For microwave ovens, this is actually really annoying, since the whole point of low power is that some foods are ruined by too much power. Unless I'm remembering incorrectly, early models really did have different power settings, and most (at least inexpensive) modern ones just do the coarse PWM thing.

Comment: @Shufflepants Some microwaves these days actually do step the power.  More even heating and you don't hear the unit cycle on and off.  Ours will also share the circuit with another high-power appliance when it's at a low power setting.

Comment: Incase anyone is interested.. for systems like this to get as accurate to the target value as possible you almost always need to implement a proportional–integral–derivative loop in to the system based on the feedback from sensors, just switching it on and off based on a set value rarely ever works for systems of anything above a relatively low level of complexity.

Comment: @Flater An even more obvious analogy might be cruise control. A thermostat works like cruise control.

Comment: @henning: That's actually not true for my cruise control (Mini One, CC from BMW). The bigger the difference in speed, the faster the car will accelerate/decelerate (up to a point, of course). If I move from a 90 km/h to a 120 km/h zone, I will often set it to 130-140 until I hit 120. It's notably faster. But my cruise control has other features, such as allowing me to shift gear (without it stopping the CC) and it has access to my car's brakes for deceleration. As I understand it, that's not the case for every CC.

Comment: @Meower68 Based off of experience with PWM fans, for a PC, if you jack up the heat higher; the PWM cycle spends more time on drawing additional power, which would lead to heating a room faster. Ideally you'd have a power curve that draws max power immediately, and steps down. I do not believe most thermastats are designed for this so it needs to be done manually, and adjusted to the target temperature once a comfortable temperature is reached.

Answer (score 31):

The thermostat in a heater is usually an on-off device. It senses the *room temperature* and runs the heater at full power as long as the room is colder than the target temperature. If the room is hotter than the target temperature,  the thermostat turns the heater off.

(In a narrow temperature interval around the target temperature the thermostat will usually stay in the state it had the last time the temperature was *outside* the target interval, such that it won't incessantly turn on and off based on fractions of degrees of difference).

Your description sounds like you're expecting the thermostat to be based on the temperature of the heating element inside the heater, but manufacturers do their best to *avoid* that and instead let it sense the *actual air temperature* in the room, since that it what you as the user actually have a preferrence for.

Comment: I always got the last part wrong. I thought turning up the thermostat resulted in the heater being warmer while warming up the room until a certain temperature was reached.

Comment: @Limechime Some control systems are like this; that is, the bigger the error signal (in this case the difference between the thermostat setting and the actual temperature), the harder the controller drives  the correction, with the drive becoming more relaxed as the error lessens. But heaters are generally not like this; one wants the error corrected as fast as possible (the room has to get to the wished-for temperature as soon as it can) and that means that the heater drives as hard as it can. Minimizing error as fast as possible is not always desirable: it can give rise to unstable dynamics.

Comment: the more commonly used buzzword is bang-bang (instead of on-off) control.

Comment: Though some more high-tech furnaces (such as the Lennox I had installed a few years ago in my home) have a variable heat output based on input from a smart thermostat, and do change the amount of heat coming out depending on how much of a difference there is between the set point and actual room temperature.  So while close to the set point, my furnace runs at a low heat, but if I adjust it to be several degrees different it will ramp up and run at a higher heat output until it gets close to the setpoint, then it will ramp down to a less intense heat output.

Comment: Which heads you into the world of PID controllers (or their digital counterparts). **P**roportional: the further you are away, the harder you try to get to the target (but for a heater this clamps to the maximum output pretty quickly); **I**ntegral: removes a "fixed offset" error that is common for proportional alone; **D**erivative: dampens oscillations above and below the target value (see [PID on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller)).

Comment: @Milwrdfan I used to have a two-stage furnace with a one-stage thermostat: it ran at low for up to 15 minutes, then switched to high. Next time it would run on high, and if it stopped in less than 5 minutes it went back to low. Sometimes back and forth, over and over. Something to get caught on while meditating for long times...

Comment: I have a free-standing heater that senses the temperature of the heater, so turning it up higher *does* actually make it heat the room faster. I imagine that's typical of free-standing heaters simply because there's nowhere else to put the sensor!

Comment: Since those sensors must be on the body of a heater which has a very high temperature, it's hard to actualy estimate the temperature of the room. Making them a bit of a bad choice.

Answer (score 6):

To add to the otherwise good answers...

The OP says in an edit that they are only talking about a convection heater.  If the heater only has one heating element, then the answers about when the thermostat turns off are broadly true.

If the heater has multiple heating elements though, you can turn on more of them.  Old-fashioned electric fires in the UK typically had up to 3 heating elements.  The more heat the fire puts out, the faster you'll get up to temperature.

The same principle applies to central heating systems too.  Most boilers allow you to set the temperature of the water circulating round the radiators.  If you increase the temperature here, all your radiators will now be hotter and rooms will heat up more quickly.  Do be warned though that this can be a real safety hazard, especially if there are small children in the house.

This does assume the air from the heater is evenly mixed around the room, of course.  This is not always true, if for example you have a small heater in a large room.  In this case you may want to turn the thermostat to maximum until the corners of the room are broadly warm, and the centre of the room is too hot.  You can then reduce the thermostat to a more sensible "steady-state" temperature, and allow normal air circulation to even out the temperature.

Note that by doing this, you are technically applying "feed-forward control" - with a control system which doesn't quite deliver what you want, you're tweaking the control system's setpoint now to allow for what the system should be doing in future.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to answers, I simulated an example setup to show the differences. In your case, only the referance value of the controller is changing.

I have trouble with imgur, so I also posted images online.

Model:
https://s18.postimg.org/71vo9wq0p/image.png

Plot: https://s18.postimg.org/rm0i8el7d/image.png

Comparison: https://s18.postimg.org/4xbb8tw3t/image.png

[image: Model]
[image: Plot of temperature]
[image: Comparison of 2 different referance values]